# trying to use SpeechSynthesizer and NAudio but process cannot access the file

Tags: c#, .net, naudio, speech-synthesis, speechsynthesizer

I am trying to use SpeechSynthesizer and NAduio, my code is below. I can't seem to get it to work though. I am getting the error message,

> The process cannot access the file 'some file.wav' because it is being used by another process.

It happens on the line,

> wave = new WaveFileReader(path + fileName);

In the synth_SpeakCompleted method.

I do not understand though what is using the file? The SpeechSynthesizer has completed creating the file as the event has been raised. Obviously I am missing something.

I am only saving the file because I don't know how to go directly from SpeechSynthesizer to NAudio so if there is a solution that doesn't save a file that would be great.

The file is fine and works perfectly when I run it manually.

```
      using NAudio.Wave;

      public partial class MainWindow : Window
      {

        private WaveFileReader wave = null;
        private DirectSoundOut output = null;
        SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = null;

        private void DrawContent()
        {
              string path = @"C:\Users\MyPath\";
              string fileName = "MyFile.wav";

              // delete previous file if it exists
              if (File.Exists(path + fileName))
                  File.Delete(path + fileName);

              synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
              synthesizer.Volume = 100;  // 0...100
              synthesizer.Rate = 3;     // -10...10

              synthesizer.SetOutputToWaveFile(path + fileName);
              synthesizer.SpeakCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>(synth_SpeakCompleted);
              synthesizer.SpeakAsync(someText);



         }

    void synth_SpeakCompleted(object sender, SpeakCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        synthesizer.SetOutputToNull();

        string path = @"C:\Users\MyPath\";
        string fileName = "MyFile.wav";

        wave = new WaveFileReader(path + fileName);
        output = new DirectSoundOut();
        output.Init(new WaveChannel32(wave));
        output.Play();

    }

    private void DisposeWave()
    {
        if(output != null)
        {
            if (output.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                output.Stop();

            output.Dispose();
            output = null;
        }

        if(wave != null)
        {
            wave.Dispose();
            wave = null;
        }
    }


  }
```

Comment: The SpeechCompleted event does not get raised at the moment you hope for.  It will keep using the stream until you tell it explicitly that you're done with it.  Make the *synthesizer* variable a member of your class, call its Dispose() method in the event handler.  Calling SetOutputToNull() gets it done as well, helps you to re-use the object.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for that comment. I have made the edits to my code and no longer debugs. However nothing plays, don't see why though?

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your help, the final step was using the WaveOut class rather than the DirectSoundOut, don't know why but it now works. If you put your comment as an answer happy to mark it as correct

Comment: Maybe DirectSoundOut was playing out of the wrong device.